# Unable to create a View with Content Revision relationships. Table workbench_revision_tracker doesn't exist

Tags: views

I'm working with a View that is supposed to pull in certain content types only if they have 1 or more revisions (i.e., content that has been updated recently). However, when I try to add a relationship in the view to `Content latest revision`, the page throws an SQL error that the table `workbench_revision_tracker` doesn't exist.

I found [this issue on the Drupal site](https://www.drupal.org/node/2847078) that says:

> So it looks like WBM's revision tracker creates its table on-demand.
>
> ... if you want to add a Views relationship to the latest revision of the node, you'd better be damn sure you **already have at least one versioned node** in the database, or you will get horrible SQL errors as soon as you add the relationship

I created an article and updated (changed body, etc.) it a couple of times after it was published, and thought that created a revision, but the table still does not exist in the database. The "create new revision" checkbox was checked at the time of updating.

How do I correctly query for content in a View that has been updated?

I'm using Drupal 8.

Comment: The linked issue has a patch.  Did you try applying the patch?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Yup, tried the patch, but it said it was already applied. Checked the code for that module and sure enough, it already matched the patch file.

Comment: If you are sure that the patch is already applied to the module's code by the maintainers and you didn't do it yourself, you should update the drupal.org issue then-- a bug report with a patch should not be marked "needs work" on d.o if the patch has already been committed to the module.